# Undelete question about easter eggs in R?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I googled 'easter eggs in R' and didn't see a Stack Overflow question/answer, which surprised me.

I knew of ruby's [`IRB.send(:easter_egg)`](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/lcf1b8/ruby_27_easter_egg_in_irb/), and python's [`import this`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python#Principles), and note that questions like [(what is the) Purpose of import this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577404/purpose-of-import-this) are left open. Two fun examples of easter eggs in those respective languages, but I knew of none in [R](https://www.r-project.org/about.html).

I was disappointed to see that [Are there any Easter eggs in base R or in major packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910270/are-there-any-easter-eggs-in-base-r-or-in-major-packages) was deleted.

Please consider undeleting, as I do not believe it is unfocused, nor is it not a coding question.

Since deleted questions aren't visible to everyone, here's a screenshot of question:

> [image]

I realise that simply voting undelete will not suffice, since:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

So I wonder if it can be reinstated via moderator intervention?

Comment: I don't think the comparison between the R and Python question is valid. One is asking for any examples, which is broad, and the other is asking about a specific example, which is focused.

Comment: Real question though: why should "a list of easter eggs" (that is open-ended list with no/every answer is correct) be on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @cigien that's a fair point. I include it for a bit of context, but agree it's not a particularly strong argument.

Comment: @AndrewT. I guess that's the key question. I guess the strongest argument for it is that, if it's part of the language, then it's as valid as asking about any other code-specific thing about the language. Others might have better cases, but that's mine.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's focused or on-topic (I'm unsure myself), I think this is worth undeleting, because it adds value to the site by providing interesting information.  Plenty of blatantly off-topic questions are left closed but not deleted because someone might get value from them.

Comment: I can see some people searching up "Easter eggs in [language]". I think it has some value to be kept.  I'm not familiar enough with R to know if it is focused, but I think it could be at least undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

The question is ***not*** on-topic.

It's not focused, and it's not about a practical programming issue.

Furthermore, it doesn't merit an [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/348149).

Being mod-deleted is a nice way to prevent delete-undelete loops on an off-topic question.

Comment: If someone wants the easter eggs on any language, there's always reddit. I heard they like fun. Also, [this already exist](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/04/r-pkg-easter-eggs-revenge-of-pacman/)